# Generalization of $f: [0,1] \to [0, 1]$ has a fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is a continuous map, there exists $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = x$.  This can be proven by applying IVT to $f(x) - x$.  Does this fact generalize to continuous maps $f: X \to X$ where $X$ is a compact topological space?

Comment: A more interesting question might be to ask about compact *connected* spaces. See the answer below.

Comment: This appears to be quite similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136644)

Answer (score 5):

One generalisation is [Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).

Answer (score 4):

There are several generalizations of the result, but as Andre remarks, the sentence you stated is not true. One generalization of what you said is the [Brouwer fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem), which states that "every continuous function $f$ from a convex compact subset $K$ of a Euclidean space to $K$ itself has a fixed point." There is also the [Lefschetz fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem), which counts the fixed points of a continuous function via computations of the homology groups of a compact triangulable space. An interesting consequence of this theorem is that a generic map of such a space $X$ that is homotopic to the identity map will have $\chi(X)$ fixed points, where $\chi(X)$ is the Euler characteristic of $X$!

Answer (score 3):

A connected counterexample is obtained by taking $X$ to be a circle or closed annulus in the plane and $f$ to be a rotation of $X$ about its centre through an angle $\theta$ that is not an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: Careful - I think you want to leave the unit disk off, since the rotation you mention fixes the origin.

Comment: @nrpeterson: I do indeed: I meant to include annuli, not disks! Thanks.

Comment: Well in that case, kudos; you don't see many people bringing up annuli out of the blue.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the case of the map $f: S^1\to S^1$ where every point is rotated by the same non-zero amount.

Edit: As Patrick correctly pointed out, the amount should be any value except for

integer multiples of $2$ $\pi$ (which includes 0)

Comment: You mean the same non-$2\pi$-integer-multiple amount. Nice example, +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=[0,1] \cup [2,3]$, and let $f$ take $[0,1]$ nicely to $[2,3]$, and vice-versa.

Comment: Or equivalently $X=\{0,1\}$ (equipped with discrete topology) and $f$ swaps the two points.