# With $X$ compact Hausdorff space and $f:X \to X$ is continuous, prove there exists a closed set $C$ such that $f( C)=C$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

> Prove that if $X$ is a non-empty topological Hausdorff compact space and $f : X\to X$ is continuous, there exists a non-empty closed set $C \subset X$ such that $f(C)=C$.

My thoughts are to show that we can travel from a starting point $x$ through $f(x),f(f(x)),...,f^n(x)$ such that $f^n(x)=x$. that's we found a closed set. I can't seem to find the use of $f$ being continuous. Thanks!

Comment: Some related posts: [Fixed Set Property?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127020) and [Analogue to Fixed Point Theorem for Compact metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136644).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought, similar to yours, was to consider the sequence $f^n(X)$. Then you have a nested sequence of compact sets, the intersection of which must be non-empty and compact (hence closed). This intersection is an example of a closed set $C$ such that $f(C) = C$.